# images in grid not stacking

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code for my images:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div class="spacer">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<% @pictures.each do |picture|%>
  <div class="picture">
    <h3><%= picture.title %></h3>
    <%= image_tag picture.picture_url.to_s, :controls =>true, :width => '75%' %>
  </div>
<%end%>
<div class="spacer">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.picture {
  flex: 30%;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  float: left;
}

.picture h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
  clear: both;
}
```

However my images are not stacking !

picture: [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCXuL.png)

I want each image to stack under the previous one, but as my picture shows they are simply starting new rows. I am baffled by this! I tried adding a

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .picture {
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

as instructed by w3schools, but it didn't do anything.

Any help would be appriciated !!

Comment: I have to ask, instructed by W3Schools where?

Comment: Are you talking about this example? https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_image_gallery ... cause your code really doesn't look like this example.

Comment: Hi, please make a working code snippet, thanks